# When should a music player gain and give up audio focus?

Tags: android

I'm writing an Android music player, and is stuck on audio focus issue.

It seems like audio focus mainly affects media button receiving, but after reading the document I have no idea about when to gain and give up focus.

My music app will run in background, and need to detect play/pause button **every time**. That is, even when my app is not running, a user should be able to press headset's play button and start music.

It seems I should never give up audio focus, so why should I implement it?

Does anyone know practically how audio focus should be used? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems like audio focus mainly affects media button receiving, but
>   after reading the document I have no idea about when to gain and give
>   up focus.

They both are separate functionalities, and thus have separate listeners. You may have audio focus taken away from you but you may still choose to respond to play pause hardware keys

> That is, even when my app is not running, a user should be able to
>   press headset's play button and start music.

I am assuming that you meant by the above line is that you are still playing music but not showing an activity. To keep listening to hardware button press, dont unregister your media button receiver(dont call `audioManager.unregisterMediaButtonEventReceiver(receiver)` yet).

> It seems I should never give up audio focus, so why should I implement
>   it?

you dont give up the focus , it gets taken from you. To handle that gracefully you have AudioFocus listener. For ex, consider an incoming phone call. Would you still like to continue playing your music?